# Testing static java methods with arguments as functions

Tags: java, functional-programming, junit5, callable

I'd like to write a test for verification if static method receiving correct callable as an argument.
Let's say I have 2 classes:

Employee

```
public class Employee {
    public static Item getEmployeeItem() {
        return new Item((a, b) -> {
            return a * b;
        });
    }
}
```

and Item

```
public class Item {
    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> behaviour;
    Item(BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> biFunction) {
        this.behaviour = biFunction;
    }
```

}

Item has constructor with BiFunction. I'd like to to test with using junit5, Mockito, PowerMock or maybe other utills, behaviour when in case when I call

```
Item item = Employee.getEmployeeItem();
```

then appriopriate BiFunction has been delivered. How can I write such kind of test with junit5? Maybe should I use somehow ArgumentCaptor?
Can someone deliver me example?

That's actually simpler example of more advanced case which I need to test in unit way in my job:

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class EthernetExtractFilterFrameParsingNodeDefinitions {

    public static ExtractFilterTreeNodeDefinition<EthernetExtractFilter, EthernetDataTuple, IpProtocol, Option<Vector<SingleDataSet>>> getIpProtocolNodeDefinition() {
        return new ExtractFilterTreeNodeDefinition<>(
                ethernetExtractFilter -> ethernetExtractFilter.networkLayerPduFilter().ipProtocolFilter().toValueFilter(),
                getNodeBehaviour(ethernetDataTuple -> ethernetDataTuple.networkLayerPdu().getIpProtocol())
        );
    }
```

}

I have to check here if `ExtractFilterTreeNodeDefinition` was created with appropriate Functions as parameters when I call `getIpProtocolNodeDefinition()` statick method.

I'd like to be sure that first argument is correct function, correctly map extractFilter to valueFilter:

```
ethernetExtractFilter -> ethernetExtractFilter.networkLayerPduFilter().ipProtocolFilter().toValueFilter()
```

second one as well
How to approach to that problem?
I would be grateful for suggestions how to achieve that.

Comment: Does Item have any public functions that actually use the BiFunction?  Test those and only those.  You should not be testing the lambda passed to the constructor, only the behavior of the result.